# Postgres output to a tab delimmitted .txt file

Tags: postgresql

I've a requirement where in i need to provide the client with data from a couple of postgres tables in a tab-delimmited file.I've used the following code to generate it in a .tsv file.
But he's come back asking me to provide it in a tab delimmited csv file.

Can you please suggest me as how this can be done apart from re-naming or moving it to .txt file.

Regards,
Vijay

```
psql -d vijay -U postgres -t -A -c "select a.key,a.name,cf.categories,cf.features,regexp_replace(a.iphone_description, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ),a.sms_name,replace(a.sms_address,',',':'),a.sms_phone,a.sms_subscribe_string,a.iphone_name,replace(a.iphone_address,',',':'),a.iphone_city,a.iphone_state_key,a.iphone_zip,a.iphone_phone,a.iphone_logo_suffix,a.iphone_banner_suffix,a.iphone_url,a.start_date,a.end_date,a.disabled,a.is_deletable,a.cms_type,a.deleted,a.banner_enabled,a.latitude,a.longitude from .advertiser a LEFT OUTER JOIN (select cat.ad_key as key,fe.name,cat.categories,fe.features from .temp_cat cat FULL OUTER JOIN .temp_features fe on (cat.ad_key=fe.key))cf ON (a.key=cf.key) and a.cms_type='poi'" > poi_10072014.tsv


regexp_replace(a.iphone_description, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' )


COPY (select a.key,a.name,cf.categories,cf.features,regexp_replace(a.iphone_description, E'\n|\r',' ', 'g' ),a.sms_name,replace(a.sms_address,',',':'),a.sms_phone,a.sms_subscribe_string,a.iphone_name,replace(a.iphone_address,',',':'),a.iphone_city,a.iphone_state_key,a.iphone_zip,a.iphone_phone,a.iphone_logo_suffix,a.iphone_banner_suffix,a.iphone_url,a.start_date,a.end_date,a.disabled,a.is_deletable,a.cms_type,a.deleted,a.banner_enabled,a.latitude,a.longitude from advertiser a LEFT OUTER JOIN (select cat.ad_key as key,fe.name,cat.categories,fe.features from temp_cat cat FULL OUTER JOIN temp_features fe on (cat.ad_key=fe.key))cf ON (a.key=cf.key) and a.cms_type='poi') TO 'poi_11072014.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" at character 6
LINE 1: COPY (select a.key,a.name,cf.categories,cf.features,regexp_r...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use COPY command like below:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME) TO 'D:\Demo1.tsv'
```

more info [COPY IN POSTGRESQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-copy.html)

**EDIT FOR .txt File:**

```
 COPY (SELECT * FROM t_offer_master) TO 'D:\Demo1.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t';
```

**Edit for \n , \r replace**

```
COPY (SELECT id,regexp_replace(name,E'\n|\r',' ','g') FROM table_name) TO 'D:\
    Demo1.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t';
```

Comment: @VJAI: It *is* tab-delimited... And if you want a .txt extension, just pick a different name.

Comment: Illesh,that would work great....but my problem is I have some columns which have many un-wanted spaces,new line chars etc in them and i need to rip them off,which I cannot perform using copy(I suppose).Is there a way to get through this...Added the command in Edit for the question...

Comment: @VJAI: You can put whatever query you want in the `COPY` command (including the one in your question).

Comment: Illesh,thanks!I tried your query but couldn't egt out put due to an error.Nick Thanks for your advice about just putting a different name...I hope it works...will get back to you.Added the error message in the edit.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked but I've a question..my present query returns | as a tab-delimitter and I want to replace it with a ' '(tab space).Can you please help me with it? The present query is writing as 1|vjai Furnitures but I want the output as 1  vjai furnitures...

Comment: I've used the command -F $'\t' to get it in the required format.

Comment: Add  `NULL E''` to the end of the command to get rid of the \N in all of the null fields which kinda screws things up when importing the resulting file into another platform.